# How to convert string bytecode to bytecode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, bytecode

I have a string bytecode like this `"b'gAAAAABicrsec2Ce4oBYs4pzEpEHou1ZkR4IHai76C9TJHHVk5KOtJ4d154qBhNqf9LGB4svlQkPHue2XNQJUtp8ZLe9dqzk8w=='"`

and I want it as bytecode type like this `b'gAAAAABicrsec2Ce4oBYs4pzEpEHou1ZkR4IHai76C9TJHHVk5KOtJ4d154qBhNqf9LGB4svlQkPHue2XNQJUtp8ZLe9dqzk8w=='`

Comment: the string byte code is in a variable.

Comment: The original string bytestring can be passed into `ast.literal_eval` and a bytestring (`bytes`) object will be returned.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't technically bytecode, it's a bytestring. Bytecode is the language that Python is compiled into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ast` module can be used to convert the bytecode base64 `str` into a proper bytestring (`bytes`) object.

Example:

```
import ast

x = "b'gAAAAABicrsec2Ce4oBYs4pzEpEHou1ZkR4IHai76C9TJHHVk5KOtJ4d154qBhNqf9LGB4svlQkPHue2XNQJUtp8ZLe9dqzk8w=='"
out = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
b'gAAAAABicrsec2Ce4oBYs4pzEpEHou1ZkR4IHai76C9TJHHVk5KOtJ4d154qBhNqf9LGB4svlQkPHue2XNQJUtp8ZLe9dqzk8w=='

>>> type(out)
bytes
```